# Jobtrackernotyetrunning Error?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTrackerNotYetInitializedException: JobTracker is not yet RUNNING

When i am trying to run a MR job, I am getting this error.

Any clues ?

Answer (score 0):

It was the problem with namenode not being formatted.